# org babel sh using sudo failed

Tags: emacs, org-babel

I am using org babel to install nvidia cuda. Howver when I am using

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo::
sudo /home/oo/Downloads/cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run
#+END_SRC
```

The evaluation failed with:

```
`/home/oo/Downloads/cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux.run: 437: exec: -title: not found
```

Comment: Did you try executing it outside of org mode, e.g. at a shell prompt? The error comes from the cuda script, not babel.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the script from the nvidia cuda website. So the script have no problem running outside. However when evaluating with org mode, failed.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention above, there must be some error in the cuda script itself, line 437 in particular. That's where you should look to resolve your problem.

EDIT: I looked at the script: it uses the variable $XTERM which seems not to be defined. In fact, line 437 is

```
                exec $XTERM -title "$label" -e "$0" --xwin "$initargs"
```

and $XTERM is replaced by nothing, leaving `-title` as the "command" to execute and triggering your error message. XTERM is supposed to be defined in the loop above (lines 428-434) but that seems not to set it at all in the emacs environment (and I cannot see why it would set it in the shell prompt in that case). Normally, I would suggest that you execute it with `bash -x` to find out more, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

You might want to try executing with the `--nox11` option which should bypass this whole section.

Since it works from the command line, why not execute it like that and be done with it? Why do you need to run it from a source block?

---

However, I also wanted to point out that you do not need to use `sudo` in the body of the code block: specifying `:dir /sudo::` says "execute the body in the directory `/sudo::` which is a pseudo-directory that is interpreted by [Tramp](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#index-sudo-method) as a method to open a file with `sudo` privileges, and then the body of the source block is executed in that context:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo::
pwd
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /root

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :dir /sudo::
id
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)  context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

As you can see, in a `:dir /sudo::` context, my working directory is `/root` and my `uid` is `0(root)`.

Alternatively, you could use sudo in the body of the block and omit the `:dir` specification:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
sudo id
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

And, yes, you *can* do both as you did, but it's overkill.

Comment: Tnansk for the peply.